# Store different dates from Firebase in uitableview cell.detailTextLabel - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that imports a users weight measurements and displays it in a table view. I want the corresponding date shown in my firebase database to be shown in the detail label. At the moment everytime I refresh the table with a new entry on a different day, the whole table refreshes to match the date. What changes can I do to fix this. (see images below)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WeightViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Declarations of Database and Added Exercise
    var addMes:[String] = []
    var handle: DatabaseHandle?
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var keyArray: [String] = []


    // Storyboard connections
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mesView: UITextField!
    @IBAction func inputButton(_ sender: Any) {

        // Current user insert of exercise
        if mesView.text != "" {
            ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("weight").child("\(getDate())").setValue(mesView.text)
            mesView.text = ""
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Nice One!", message: "Your weight has been stored. If you want to amend, just enter a new weight and it will be overwritten for today. ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
            // Alert if nothing is entered
            if mesView.text == "" {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oh dear...", message: "You can't submit nothing", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    // Table returns number of exercises
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addMes.count
    }
    // Cell textLabel equals exercise entered
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = addMes[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = getDate()
        return cell
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Adds target to add measurement type
        mesView.delegate = self
        mesView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

        // Start of hide keyboard
        self.mesView.delegate = self

        // Database Reference
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        // Adds notes child
        handle = ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("weight").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String
            {
                self.addMes.append(item)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }
    // Adds measurement
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(textfield: UITextField) {
        var text = mesView.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "kg", with: "")
        text = text! + "kg"
        mesView.text = text

        print("Text changed")
    }
    // Allows editing of cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    // Delete cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            GetAllKeys()
            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {
                self.ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("weight").child(self.keyArray[indexPath.row]).removeValue()

                self.addMes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.keyArray = []
            })
        }

    }
    // Retrieves all keys from Firebase
    func GetAllKeys() {
        ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("weight").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                self.keyArray.append(key)
            }
        })
    }
    // End of hide keyboard when user touches outside keyboard
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    //Presses return key
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        mesView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }
    func getDate() -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        // hours + min:  -\(calendar.component(.hour, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.minute, from: date))
        return "\(calendar.component(.year, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.month, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.day, from: date))"
    }
    // How button pressed
    @IBAction func How(_ sender: Any) { UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.wikihow.com/Take-Body-Measurements")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase data tree]

[image]

Comment: You are fetching the date on runtime, so for each cell it will only show the current date, say 2018-3-29 in your case. To avoid this you need to store the date with message in your `addMes` array. you can keep `addMes` as `[String: String]` - array of dictionary with one pair of message and one pair of date.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Sorry been stuck on this for ages, how can I implement it using my code?

Comment: Where you are loading `addMes` array. Log the whole code please.

Comment: So sorry I don't understand, I've adde the whole of my code if that helps?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, ` handle = ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("weight").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in` - what information does Snapshot contains? Can you log that also please, so that I can answer your question. (for ex, `snapshot.value` is weight)

Comment: Yes the snapshot contains whatever is entered by the user i.e 75kg and then it is added back to the table view via `self.addExer.append(item)`
           `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168246/discussion-between-ankit-jayaswal-and-connor-berry).

Comment: This was kind of said previously but each time you display a cell in your tableView, you call getDate so every cell will have the same date and it will be updated to the currentDate whenever the tableView is refreshed. It appears the date component is being stored as the key to the weight so when you are reading the weights, snapshot.key would be the date. I would NOT recommend storing it like this - it would be better to create the child nodes with .childByAutoId and store the data as child nodes of  weight: "some weight" and date: "some date" within each node.